# Timeout connecting to Elastic Search, both ES and Lambda are in the same VPC AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, vpc, amazon-opensearch

Timeout connecting to Elastic Search, both ES and Lambda are in the same VPC.

The lambda role allows it to access all "es:*" and the VPC allows any resource to access as well.  The security group both are attached to allow all traffic inbound/outbound 0.0.0.0.  The vpc has public and private subnets.

Lambda is added to 2 public and private subnets of the vpc.

I keep hitting time out when trying to connect to the ES.  I am able to access the ES via kibana.

Not able to share specifics in code but can answer questions in generality.

Comment: Is the lambda function in Public or Private subnet

Comment: i added the lambda to both public and private net of the vpc manually via aws console

Comment: You have to keep the Lambda to Private subnet only and then try

Comment: Removed public subnet from lambda and just tested it.  Same error.  Not sure if this has any impact, I am triggering the lambda via API Gateway. The last successful logout is right before my RestHighLevelClient executes a search.

Comment: What is the network configuration of the Elasticsearch cluster? What are the security group rules?

Comment: Network configuration is that both ES and Lambda in same VPC.  Security group was all traffic inbound 0.0.0.0 and all traffic outbound 0.0.0.0.  I completely opened it to rule out security group